# How to set pandas series index from a dataframe and fill the series with other data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `myDataFrame` with many columns and a multiple index(es) (two)
I want to create a series that has the same indexing as my dataframe `myDataFrame` but at each row I set a value.

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
mySeries.set_index(myDataFrame.index)

for i in mySeries.index()
   mySeries.loc[i] = someValue
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
 pd.Series(somevalue, index = df.index)
```